# Scala getting a collection back when the compiler says that it has type Any

Tags: list, scala, collections, types

With Scala, I am able to get the following:

```
res56: Any = 
List(List(0.0, hello world), List(0.0, huzzah!), List(0.0, herp a erp), List(0.0, Open up), List(0.0, "WHY!! That FACE!"))
```

Why does Scala believe that this has Type `Any` and why can't I just use `asInstanceOf[List[List[Double,String]]]` I've seen this happen with `Maps` as well. I am not sure what else I can do...

Thanks for all the help!

**Edit:** Thanks for the generally accepted answer: `List[(Double, String)]`, but how do I get there? For example, how can you easily cast to a type like this? In the past for a lot of collections, I have had to do really long and strange casts with a lot of `.toList.asInstanceOf`

Is there a shorter way to simply convert something of this form to `List[(Double,String)]`

Comment: The answer's explained why you get `Any` as the element type of the list - list elements must all be of the same type and the common super type of `Double` and `String` is `Any`. If you want a heterogeneous list, maybe you could use a tuple `(0.0, "hello world")` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections in the scala standard library are monomorphic, i.e. all the elements in the `List` must have the same type.

`Map` is no difference: it has **one** type for the key and **one** type for the value, or if you prefer you can see `Map` as a container of tuples (key, value), and there's **one** type for the tuple.

When you put heterogeneous elements into a `List`, the compiler infers the strictest supertype of the elements, which in case of `String` and `Double` is `Any`.

Conversely tuples have the property you desire: each element holds its own type.

In your specific example:

```
List((0.0, "hello world"), (0.0, "huzzah!"), (0.0, "herp a erp"), (0.0, "Open up"), (0.0, "WHY!! That FACE!"))
```

this will produce a `List[(Double, String)]`.

The limitation of tuples is that their length is fixed (2 in this case).

If you need something that combines the variable-length property of lists and the type precision of tuples, you might want to checkout shapeless' `HList` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is defined as `List[+A]`. So it has one type, not two types. The combination of `Double` and `String` is `Any`. In REPL, the type is shown as `List[List[Any]]` which is correct.

```
scala> List(List(0.0,"hello world"), List(0.0, "huzzah!"), List(0.0,"herp a erp"), List(0.0, "Open up"), List(0.0, "WHY!! That FACE!"))
res30: List[List[Any]] = List(List(0.0, hello world), List(0.0, huzzah!), List(0.0, herp a erp), List(0.0, Open up), List(0.0, WHY!! That FACE!))
```

You can use `Tuples` to get type similar to `Double,String`

```
scala> List(List((0.0,"hello world")), List((0.0, "huzzah!")), List((0.0,"herp a erp")), List((0.0, "Open up")), List((0.0, "WHY!! That FACE!")))
res31: List[List[(Double, String)]] = List(List((0.0,hello world)), List((0.0,huzzah!)), List((0.0,herp a erp)), List((0.0,Open up)), List((0.0,WHY!! That FACE!)))
```